# What does a music producer do at a concert?

Tags: live-music, concert

It's a doubt I have since when I started listening to electronic music. In my head, electronic music is created [like this](https://youtu.be/vy7olhBeCcQ), i.e. sitting at a computer in a comfortable room. There is no real time performing, just a lot of time to spend composing and letting the computer process what you composed.

So what do electronic music producers do at a live concert? I can imagine them playing the main melody on a keyboard or a particular beat on a pad, but there are way more effects and sounds in the average song that what is possible to reproduce with just two hands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Skrillex perform live concerts?](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/612/how-does-skrillex-perform-live-concerts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this [Launchpad video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMgxLPcq-3o) you can have a simplified exemple of what can be a live performance of an electronic music artist.

As you said, on his quiet studio time, the artist can create his various *stems*, nice and clean ready to be played at a live show. He will also select samples (extract from other artists music).

In the live performance, like an orchestra conductor, he will start a stem when he wants. Once the stem is playing, his hands are now free, he can ad various effects (*EQ*, *Reverbs*...), starting another stem, starting a sample etc... or actually play an instrument while the background music is playing.
He also can feel the audience, and decide the right moment to *drop the beat*.

So, like any artist, each live performance will be different from each other.